# Говорим: семья, подразумеваем: члены семьи, - что делать с согласованием?

Tags: выбор-слов, согласование

> Единственно, кто может повлиять на мои решения, это моя семья. Но я
>   считаю это правильным. Самое главное для меня – семья. Только из-за
>   них я готов делать то, что не очень хотелось бы. Но опять-таки – таков
>   мой выбор.

Всё в порядке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Только из-за нее" правильнее, я тоже споткнулась о "только из-за них".

А не слишком много личных местоимений? Качества хорошей речи они не прибавляют. Может, заменить на "из-за близких"?

Comment: Угу! Отправляя сюда вопрос и с тоской глядя на безобразию, я  - в последний миг - заменила на "родных". )))

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, "Только из-за них" допустимо, но лучше простое решение: "Только из-за нее".